Show that $|\rm{Aut}(G)|=48$ for the cube graph
Let $Q$ denote the cube graph (i.e. the graph that looks like a cube in 3D).
I am interested in how to prove that $|\rm{Aut}(Q)|=48$.
I see that one can write down $48$ elements, so $|\rm{Aut}(Q)|\geq 48$. But I cannot see why there can't be more automorphisms (that we missed to mention). How/When can we be sure that we have found all of them? Can one show this in a purely graph-theoretical way?
A priori, we only have $\rm{Aut}(Q)=:H\leq S_8$.
This is related to the following question:
Automorphism group and congruences of the cube
Thank you very much for the help.

Intuitively: If you pick one side of the cube for example the vertices $(1,2,3,4)$, and interpret this as dihedral group $D_4$, you can then use all 8 automorphism of $D_4$ to choose  their position and then choose one of the six sides on the cube for this fixed position of the four vertices. The position of the remaining vertices is then uniquely determined by this. So there are $6\cdot 8 = 48$ possible automorphisms.

The orbit stabilizer approach works really well here. You can do it with a vertex (86), an edge (124), a side (68), or even the ordered set of diagonals (242).

We can compute the order of the automorphism group in the following way. It should be clear geometrically that $G = \text{Aut}(Q)$ acts transitively on the vertices. So the action of $G$ on vertices is isomorphic to $G/H$ where $H$ is the stabilizer of any vertex. $H$ is a smaller group and if we can compute its order then
$$|G| = |H| |G/H| = 8 |H|.$$
So we want to see why $|H| = 6$. This is the order of $S_3$, and there's a natural collection of $3$ things to look at here, namely, if we fix a vertex $v$, it has $3$ neighbors, and elements of $H$ must permute them. Every permutation occurs so $|H| \ge 6$.
Now I claim that if you know what $H$ does to the $3$ neighbors of $v$ then this uniquely determines what $H$ does to the entire graph. The rest of the graph consists of the point $-v$ diagonally opposite to $v$, which is uniquely determined by the fact that it is furthest away (in the path metric, so this is determined by the structure of the graph only), and its neighbors. Because $-v$ is uniquely determined by its relationship to $v$, every element of $H$ fixes it. The other $3$ vertices, which are the neighbors of $-v$, are determined by which of the $3$ neighbors of $v$ they are adjacent to, or alternatively by which of the $3$ neighbors of $v$ they are opposite to. Here's a picture drawn in quiver:

So $H \cong S_3$ which gives $|G| = 48$ as desired. In fact $G$ is the wreath product $C_2 \wr S_3 \cong C_2^3 \rtimes S_3$.

The automorphism group of the cube acts simply transitively on the embedding of the $D_4$ graph into the cube. There are 48 such embeddings (  $8$ vertices of the cube, $[S_3|=6$, $8\times 6 = 48$).


I mentioned in the comments that there are numerous ways to do this with the orbit stabilizer theorem. Qiaochu does it via the stabilizer of a vertex. Algebruh's comment does it via the stabilizer of a side.
You can also do it via the stabilizer of an edge. There are 12 of these, and it's clear you can rotate any edge to any other edge. So we just need to know the stabilizer of an edge. Such a stabilizer either fixes the endpoints of the edge, or swaps them. The elements that fix them are the identity, and reflection in a plane containing the edge, that cuts the cube into two triangular pieces. The elements that swap them are reflection in a plane cutting the edge and cube in half, and finally a rotation by 180 degrees around an axis through the center of the edge and the center of its diagonally opposite edge. Thus there are 4 elements in the stabilizer, and we have $48=12*4$.
Another way is to look at the ordered set of 4 diagonals in the cube, say labelling them $A,B,C,D$. With rotations you can get any permutation of these 4 diagonals, of which there are $4!=24$. The only element that fixes all 4 diagonals is the one that swaps the endpoints of all the diagonals, which is the negation map in $\mathbb{R}^3$: $\mathbf{v}\mapsto -\mathbf{v}$. So the stabilizer has order 2, and again $48=4!\cdot 2$. This version is harder to visualize, but it has some nice side effects. Because you can permute the diagonals with just rotations, and the stabilizer only contains the identity and a reflection, you see that the oriented automorphism group of the cube, which has order 24, must be $S_4$, permitting these 4 diagonals. Because the negation map commutes with all the rotations, you can see your full automorphism group must have structure $S_4\times C_2$.
